# How to add blank lines (spaces) between each log when build a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to add automatic spaces between the printed logs?

For example (Python project) if I were to print out two lines they will be stacked on each other in the output log when click build as can be seen in the screenshot.

It because I feel it's difficult for me to distinguish which is which and the logs aren't separated by spaces. Reading the output is a struggle and would appreciate if there's a way to toggle this issue. Thanx

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where do you want the whitespaces exactly? do you not want a new line at the end of each print?

Comment: If you want a newline someplace, just use `print("\n")`.

Comment: @MattDMo I do this sometimes but I was wondering if there's a better way to add that new line without me specifying that like in an auotmatic way for example

Comment: @LiorElbaz Yes. If you see down where the printed out results they're stacked on top of each other and no spaces between each print.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for key, value in user_0.items():
    print(f"Key: {key}")
    print("\n")
    print(f"Value: {value}")
    print("\n")

...
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to add a newline to your print output. The first is to put a newline character in your string to be printed:

```
for key, value in user_0.items():
    print(f"Key: {key}\n")
    print(f"Value: {value}\n)
```

or

```
for key, value in user_0.items():
    print(f"Key: {key}\n" + f"Value: {value}\n")
```

Another would be to use the `end` parameter:

```
print(f"Key: {key}", end="\n\n")
```

A third would be to create a subclass of [`pprint.PrettyPrinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter) that uses a double newline as terminator. This might be a little too complex for you at this point in the game, though.